# Диалог на тему массивов

Tags: java

```
Object a = new Integer[10];
Object[] b = new Integer[10];
```

К какому интересному диалогу может привести этот код?

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду? Код как код.

Comment: На собеседовании, вот ссылка: http://www.javenue.info/post/89

Comment: ))) вырвал кусок текста, если я не прочитал про это в топике, не за что бы не догадался при чем тут диалоги =)

Comment: если у меня спросят на собеседовании что произойдет при    

    Object o = new Object();
    o.wait();
я встану, развернусь и уйду.
По сути, такие вопросы, которые несут в себе *ересь цензура*, вызывают у меня ощущение, что компания занимается какой-то *цензура*

Answer (score 1):

Что, на самом деле работодатели такие вопросы задают ? Или просто скучно нанимателю, хочет потрепаться "о высоком" в программировании ?

Если по делу, то a Object, а b массив, от этого и зависят усилия программера по объяснению в разных контекстах туповатому Java компилятору, что по сути мы хотим  обрабатывать одни и те же байтики.

Comment: " a Object, а b массив, " ыыыы =)
ну а вообще понятно)

Comment: *"ыыыы =)"* - а простыми русскими словами, это как будет ?

Answer (score 0):

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277813/the-behaviour-of-equals-method-in-java

гугли по такому запросу: "Object a = new Integer[];" + "Object[] b = new Integer[];"
ковычки и плюс тоже нужны.

Comment: ))) плюс уже не работает в гугле)